# Saving input information into a list and the list is updated in console(python)

Tags: python, list, input

I was trying to figure out how I could save the user input into the list, after the user has inputted the information.

**Input Code**

```
        newItemName = input("Enter the name of your item:")
        priceNewItem = input("Enter the price of your item:")
        stockNewItem = input("Enter the stock of your item:")
```

**List**

```
inventory = [['Milk,   3.99,  25'],
             ['Bread,  1.99,  35'],
             ['Eggs,   1.99,  50'],
             ['Flour,  0.52,  20'],
             ['Rice,   0.72,  35']]
```

**NEW FOLLOW UP QUESTION:**

following along with this question I was wondering how I could take this user input(below) and just modify the item that is already in the list. If the user does not input the same item as show in the list then just add the input as a new grocery item.

```
modItem = input("Enter the name of an existing item you want to modify:")
modPrice = input("Enter the new price of the item:")
modStock = input("Enter the new stock of the item:")
inventory.append([modItem, modPrice, modStock])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list from the inputs and append it to the inventory.

```
inventory = [['Milk,   3.99,  25'],
             ['Bread,  1.99,  35'],
             ['Eggs,   1.99,  50'],
             ['Flour,  0.52,  20'],
             ['Rice,   0.72,  35']]

newItemName = input("Enter the name of your item:")
priceNewItem = input("Enter the price of your item:")
stockNewItem = input("Enter the stock of your item:")

inventory.append([newItemName, priceNewItem, stockNewItem])
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you can simply append the items as a list into your inventory i.e.:

```
inventory.append([newItemName, priceNewItem, stockNewItem])
```

If you wanted to modify an existing item or add a new one you can simply iterate through your inventory i.e.:

```
modItem = input("Enter the name of an existing item you want to modify:")
modPrice = input("Enter the new price of the item:")
modStock = input("Enter the new stock of the item:")

for i in inventory:
    if i[0] == modItem:
       i[1] = modPrice
       i[2] = modStock
    else:
       inventory.append([modItem, modPrice, modStock])
```